# IoT hub to Azure Edge

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

Is it possible to control a Azure Edge device through IoT hub, eg. I would like to request "an image data/ control a led connected to as IoT device to the Azure Edge runtime through IoT hub.

The Flow would be, IoT hub -- Azure Edge -- IoT device (Led sensor)..

I want to control LeD through Edge from IoT hub or by any means.

Answer (score 0):

All the Cloud-2-Device messaging features to leaf devices also work when you connect the device through an IoT Edge device as a transparent gateway.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-c2d

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/iot-edge-as-gateway

Comment: Sure @silent, Ill get with this, I have already went through the docs. So, Is it possible to send a request from the IoT hub to the Edge gateway ( say I have a image inside the gateway, and I want to send as a respond back to IoT hub), Its a 2 way communication, Is this a possible scenario between Hub and Gateway

Comment: Is there a solution to do this ?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are asking. When you say "the Edge gateway", what do you mean? A custom module that you built and deployed on your IoT Edge gateway?

Comment: Hi @silent, I'll sum up the scenario, So Azure edge ( say I have locally stored data which is stored in blob) , I would like to invoke a method and send a request from IoT hub to Edge device for that data stored in Edge . So basically IoT hub cloud to edge device , is that possible?

Comment: the Azure IoT Edge runtime (I assume thats what you mean by "Azure Edge"), is only that: a runtime. Any custom logic like "please upload an image", you have to build yourself and put into a custom module. Inside such a module you can react on cloud-2-device messages like described in the links above - and for example trigger your upload.